# Glut Headers For Delphi XE4

Tags: delphi, opengl, glut, delphi-xe4

I used Glut headers in visual studio but now I want to use it in delphi.
I can not find headers for delphi !
Glut folder contains:

```
glut.h
glut.def
glut32.dll
glut32.lib
```

How can I use them in delphi?
Is there any different header for delphi?

Answer (score 2):

In order to link to the DLL from C++ you need the header file (.h) for the compiler and the import library (.lib) for the linker.

For Delphi you cannot use either of these files. You need to translate the header file to Pascal. An example of such a translation is the Windows unit in the RTL, Windows.pas. This is a translation of various Windows header files, windows.h and more.

You need to search for a Delphi translation of the glut header file. If you cannot find one, you need to write your own translation.

Start here: http://www.google.com/search?q=glut%20delphi

Comment: I searched before and found a few Units but they don't work properly! there is some errors in units when compiling!

Comment: I guess it will take some work. Did you consider using FMX which comes with 3D graphics framework.

Comment: There's always Dr. Bob's HeadConv to help you convert a .h to .pas: http://www.drbob42.com/headconv/ There's a chance it won't work right-a-way either, but it's a take from a different direction: if you compare the code, you learn about what is going on and might find out what to correct into what.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Some, at least. Like I said, I learned more about what it takes to properly translate .h's, but hand-rolled my own since then, like this one: https://github.com/stijnsanders/TSQLite/blob/master/SQLite.pas